# Orchard persist viewmodel in driver

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I have a content type with several parts where one of them has the ability to add an agenda consisting of several points with a date, time, title and rich text description. In other words a 1-n relation.
This part uses a view model to submit the list of objects.
The user may have spent some time on the agenda before submitting, and if any of the other parts doesn't validate they currently loose all their work on the agenda.
This is not unexpected since a fresh view model is created when the page is reloaded.

However I can not help but notice that any information in a part will persist, and I was hoping there was a way to also persist the data in the view model.

The driver has the following methods:

```
protected override DriverResult Editor(AgendaPart part, dynamic shapeHelper)
{
    return ContentShape("Parts_Agenda_Edit",
        () => shapeHelper.EditorTemplate(
            TemplateName: "Parts/Agenda",
            Model: BuildEditorViewModel(part),
            Prefix: Prefix));
}

protected override DriverResult Editor(AgendaPart part, IUpdateModel updater, dynamic shapeHelper)
{
    var model = new AgendaViewModel();
    updater.TryUpdateModel(model, Prefix, null, null);

    if (part.ContentItem.Id != 0)
    {
        _agendaService.CreateUpdateAgenda(model, part.ContentItem);
    }

    return Editor(part, shapeHelper);
}
```

When submitting I get the view model like this:

```
var model = new AgendaViewModel();
updater.TryUpdateModel(model, Prefix, null, null);
```

Is there anything "similar" that can be done when loading the editor to fetch any pre-existing view model data?
If not then any other suggestions are appreciated as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC provides a mechanism for persisting such data across requests: TempData. You can see an example of this in this controller: https://bitbucket.org/bleroy/nwazet.commerce/src/b558d7988c4f6c66cdd0b2dd6b533d8ad3bfbceb/Controllers/StripeController.cs?at=default

I also want to make clear that TryUpdateModel is not doing any persistence work. What it does is that it maps data submitted by the client (typically, that's form data) onto the object that you pass in. The part records are what's keeping track of changes that can then be automatically persisted by Orchard.

Comment: This example is for a Controller, is there a TempDataDictionary available somehow from a ContentPartDriver?

Comment: You can access it from a filter: it will be a property on Controller, which is itself a property of the filter's context. Then you can copy it onto the current request's Items, or on a dynamic property of Layout, that you can access from your driver.
Session is another type of storage that would work, and that is accessible from anywhere through the current HTTP context.